# Why does Explorer Search find some matches and miss others?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Why does Explorer search find some matches and miss others? E.g. in

[image: http://i.imgur.com/BQCAE9H.png]

the first three are missed:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/gUl4txZ.png]

Comment: Try searching "Take*" (without the quotes).

Comment: I wonder why. It makes no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a failure to update the index.

If I rename the folder and search again, all matches are missing. After a few minutes, some appear. After five minutes, all appear:

[image]